# UIScrollView with UIImageView centered rotation when zoomed?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm trying to create an image viewer that behaves exactly like the Apples Photo App. But for now I'm only interested in a single image behavior.

I've placed an UIImageView inside UIScrollView and managed to handle pretty much everything beside one thing, and that is if I zoom-in in a portion of image(for example a portrait image) and then rotate the device in landscape the portion appears to be rotated over the upper left corner instead of center.

Let me try to illustrate that. This is what I have now:

[image: What I have]

This is what I would want to happen:

[image: What I want]

Basically I believe I know how I could do it but it seems to involve a bit more coding than it probably deserves. Maybe I'm missing some simple property that I could just set to get this desired behavior.

Any hint, anyone?

Comment: Did you try setting the centre point to the centre point of the view on rotation? It also looks like an anchoring problem to me. Make sure the `UIImageView` is anchored to the top *AND* the bottom. Hope that Helps!

Comment: I was not aware of the center property will try it now. On the other hand I could not figure out how I would anchor the UIImageView I only see that UIImageView layer has anchorPoint property which is a CGPoint, but I'm not too sure you meant that?

Comment: I meant to anchor it in the nib.

Comment: I would be really interested seeing that done in code... However I do remember seeing such an option in XIB/GUI editing part... So I went to look for it right now. And a strange thing is happening(I have Xcode 4.5.2 btw). When I select in the XIB an Image View and place it and go over its options in the right menu... The autosizing menu is not to be found, BUT during switching between sections (with small icons on the top of the right menu) the autosizing option appears and disappears for a fraction of a second(I had to take a camera to freeze the frame to catch it)?! Very strange!!!

Comment: That is weird. Maybe it has to do with the auto-resizing mask from Auto-Layout? Or that it is in a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: The Auto-Layout .... maybe... did you try it? I tried different objects, button, label, scroll view, table view, image view... doesn't matter, the old autosizing tab/panel flashes for few microseconds during switching...Seems to be a bug in Xcode

Comment: For the record, I did figure out why this happens. The old autosizing panel is still there and will be shown if you uncheck the Use Autolayout option.

Comment: Check out Apple's PhotoScroller sample code. They handle all this stuff.

Comment: I just did (again, because long time ago I skimmed trough their code and basically forgot about it because I though they were only explaining how to make tiled loading)... Anyhow I just tested their code with plain images (no tiles) and zoomed-in rotation works as it should. Thank you Mike for reminding me! http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I would also like to accept your comment as the right answer(so please post it when you can...). Apple sample is the way to go! Their overridden setFrame method and prepareToResize and recoverFromResizing methods contain all the code needed to properly do this. There is even a pragma mark there that says: "Methods called during rotation to preserve the zoomScale and the visible portion of the image". So that's it!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.imageView.center = self.scrollView.center;
```

Comment: Where would you put this? I've tried at the end of layoutSubviews but it works awkwardly and only OK if the user zooms-in in the dead center (because layoutSubviews is getting called on every zoom level change, so it actually disrupts the user to even be able to zoom anywhere else). Probably not the right place to call it... Also maybe the imageView.center should not be set to scrollView center but zoom region center ?... Haven't tried that one yet... Any suggestions?

Comment: scrollViewDidFinishingZooming maybe? Also yes you probably want to center it in the zoomed in region.

Comment: tried it. Didn't work for some reason... It does seem like a logical place to put it. I don't know why it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

do set    [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];